# Spark streaming rawSocketStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, protocol-buffers, spark-streaming

I am trying the spark streaming and listening to a socket, I am using the rawSocketStream method to create a receiver and a DStream. But when I print the DStream I get the below exception.

## Code to create a DStream:

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext("Master", "app");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(jsc, new Seconds(3));
JavaReceiverInputDStream<Object> rawStream = jssc.rawSocketStream("localhost", 9999);
log.info(tracePrefix + "Created the stream ...");
rawStream.print();
jssc.start();
jssc.awaitTermination();
```

## Code to send a protobug object over TCP connection:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("address_book");
AddressBook book = AddressBookProtos.AddressBook.parseFrom(input);
log.info(tracePrefix + "Size of contacts: " + book.getPersonList().size());

ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
log.info(tracePrefix + "Waiting for connections ...");
Socket s1 = serverSocket.accept();
log.info(tracePrefix + "Accepted a connection ...");
while(true) {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());
    out.writeByte(book.getSerializedSize());
    out.write(book.toByteArray());
    out.flush();
    log.info(tracePrefix + "Written to new socket");
}
```

## Stacktrace is shown below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.RawNetworkReceiver.onStart(RawInputDStream.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


2016-04-02 07:45:47,607 ERROR [Executor task launch worker-0] org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisorImpl
Stopped receiver with error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

2016-04-02 07:45:47,613 ERROR [Executor task launch worker-0] org.apache.spark.executor.Executor
Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.RawNetworkReceiver.onStart(RawInputDStream.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-04-02 07:45:47,646 ERROR [task-result-getter-0] org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager
Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job

2016-04-02 07:45:47,656 ERROR [submit-job-thread-pool-0] org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker
Receiver has been stopped. Try to restart it.

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.RawNetworkReceiver.onStart(RawInputDStream.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.RawNetworkReceiver.onStart(RawInputDStream.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

## Working code

Code sending the protobuf object over TCP

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
        log.info(tracePrefix + "Waiting for connections ...");
        Socket s1 = serverSocket.accept();
        log.info(tracePrefix + "Accepted a connection ...");
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());
            byte[] bytes = book.toByteArray();
            log.info(tracePrefix + "Serialized size: " + book.getSerializedSize());
            out.writeInt(book.getSerializedSize());
            log.info(tracePrefix + "Sending bytes: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
            out.write(bytes);
//          out.write("hello world !".getBytes());
            out.flush();
            log.info(tracePrefix + "Written to new socket");
        }
```

Code to create a Receiver and DStream

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<GeneratedMessage> rawStream = jssc.receiverStream(new JavaSocketReceiver("localhost", 9999));
log.info(tracePrefix + "Created the stream ...");
rawStream.print();

private static class JavaSocketReceiver extends Receiver<GeneratedMessage> {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -958378677169958045L;
        String host = null;
        int port = -1;

        JavaSocketReceiver(String host_, int port_) {
            super(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK());
            host = host_;
            port = port_;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    receive();
                }
            }.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
        }

        private void receive() {
            try {
                Socket socket = null;
                ObjectInputStream in = null;
                try {                   
                    // Open a socket to the target address and keep reading from
                    // it
                    log.info(tracePrefix + "Connecting to " + host + ":" + port);
                    SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
                    channel.configureBlocking(true);
                    channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
                    log.info(tracePrefix + "Connected to " + host + ":" + port);

                    ArrayBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);

                    Thread blockPushingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            int nextBlockNumber = 0;
                            while (true) {
                                try {
                                    ByteBuffer buffer = queue.take();
                                    nextBlockNumber += 1;
                                    AddressBook book = AddressBook.parseFrom(buffer.array());
//                                  log.info(tracePrefix + "Got back the object: " + book);
                                    store(book);
                                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                                    log.error(tracePrefix + "Failed processing data", ie);
                                } catch (Throwable t) {
                                    log.error(tracePrefix + "Failed processing data", t);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    blockPushingThread.setDaemon(true);

                    blockPushingThread.start();

                    ByteBuffer lengthBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
                    while (true) {
                        lengthBuffer.clear();
                        readFully(channel, lengthBuffer);
                        lengthBuffer.flip();
                        int length = lengthBuffer.getInt();
//                      log.info(tracePrefix + "The length read: " + length);
                        ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(length);
                        readFully(channel, dataBuffer);
                        dataBuffer.flip();
//                      log.info(tracePrefix + "Read a block with " + length + " bytes");
                        queue.put(dataBuffer);
                    }


                } finally {
                    Closeables.close(in, /* swallowIOException = */ true);
                    Closeables.close(socket, /* swallowIOException = */ true);
                }
            } catch (ConnectException ce) {
                ce.printStackTrace();
                restart("Could not connect", ce);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                restart("Error receiving data", t);
            }
        }

        private void readFully(ReadableByteChannel channel, ByteBuffer dest) {
            while (dest.position() < dest.limit()) {
                try {
                    if (channel.read(dest) == -1) {
                        throw new EOFException("End of channel");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error(tracePrefix + "Failed reading from channel: " + channel, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above JavaSocketReceiver is taken from the rawSocketStream of the spark streaming module. In the client code where I am sending the bytes, if I change the DataOutputStream to ObjectOutputStream I get a corrupted header exception, And in the Streaming code if I use the inbuilt rawSocketStream to listen to the incoming packets then I get a IllegalArgumentException at ByteBuffer (334)

Comment: How big is that `addressBook` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate(int)) documentation, the `IllegalArgumentException` can only be caused by trying to allocate a negative buffer size.

The `RawInputDStream` protocol requires an Integer size field followed by the corresponding payload. That field is a [4-byte Integer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/RawInputDStream.scala#L81).

The sender program shown in the question:

```
out.writeByte(book.getSerializedSize());
```

is writing the integer size as as one Byte. Hence when the reading side tries to decode the payload size, it will read a corrupt field as it will be combining this byte with some information of the payload that when decoded results in a negative integer.

The solution should be to write an 4-byte (32bits) Integer instead:

```
out.writeInt(book.getSerializedSize());
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion, your change worked with the stream when I create a Receiver myself (which was not working previosly as the length was written as byte) but with rawSocketStream I still do not have any luck :(

Comment: @LokeshKumarP RawDStream fails with the exact same error even after fixing that bug in the producer?

Comment: yes sir the same illegalargumentexcepion where capacity is < 0 in bytebuffer

Comment: Pasting the exception again: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.RawNetworkReceiver.onStart(RawInputDStream.scala:88)
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
 at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:575)

Comment: Hi, I am not getting the IllegalArgumentException when I use DataOutputStream while sending the data instead of ObjectOutputStream I am receiving the correct length at the Spark receiver, but I get this new Exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0A3F0A06, which says the header is corrupt any idea whats happening?

Comment: From the spark code, I got to know that it is using ObjectInputStream to deserialize the bytes I am sending using DataOutputStream which is not going to work ...

Answer (score 2):

I've been investigating a similar problem using the rawSocketStream method of the JavaStreamingContext class.  In my case I want to send and receive byte[] data, and I eventually got this to work.

Regarding the original question, you can achieve your objective of using rawSocketStream to receive data without having to write a custom Receiver.  The solution is based on how you use ObjectOutputStream on the sending side.  As Lokesh discovered, constructing an ObjectOutputStream object using a Socket output stream will cause an IllegalArgumentException.  However, the exception does not occur if the sender constructs the sockets and streams like this:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
```

Notice that I pass a ByteArrayOutputStream object to the ObjectOutputStream constructor.  The root problem with the original approach is that the constructor of ObjectOutputStream writes a serialization stream header to the underlying stream  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream-java.io.OutputStream-).  If the underlying stream is the clientSocket output stream, then the raw socket stream on the Spark side will immediately receive the serialization stream header data upon connection and interpret it as the 4-byte buffer size for the receiving ByteBuffer object.  Apparently the first 4 bytes of this header must have a 1 as the most significant bit, causing the receiver to interpret it as a negative integer and the ByteBuffer allocate method to throw an IlleglaArgumentException.

Next, you use the ObjectOutputStream to write serialized data to the ByteArrayOutputStream object.  Even though I am transmitting byte[] data, the `write(byte[])` method caused an exception.  I had to use the `writeObject()` method instead, passing my byte[] data into writeObject().

After the ByteArrayOutputStream is loaded, calculate its size and write the size into the socket output stream.  Make sure to write this data into the socket output stream, not ObjectOutputStream, and write the size data before writing the ByteArrayOutputStream data.  Since the size must be transmitted as 4 bytes, but the outputStream.write() method writes only the 8 low-order bits, you need to use some bit operators to transmit the correct data.

This is what the code in the sender looks like:

```
try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);) 
{
    byte[] bytes;
    //  Load the byte[] with data
    ...

    oos.writeObject(bytes);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

    outputStream.write(bos.size() >> 24);
    outputStream.write(bos.size() >> 16);
    outputStream.write(bos.size() >> 8);
    outputStream.write(bos.size());
    outputStream.write(bos.toByteArray());

    // Keep socket connections open
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

On the receiving side, the relevant code is this:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("log jamming").setMaster("local[2]");
JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1));
JavaReceiverInputDStream<byte[]> bytes = jsc.rawSocketStream("localhost", 9999);

// Have fun with the RDD

jsc.start();
jsc.awaitTermination();
```